# input type='file' transfer the value using method='post'

Tags: php

```
<form name='mainform' method='post' action='do.php?ppc/workload' >
<?php
print "<input type='hidden' name='ppc_m_id' value='$id'>";
print "<table class='clean_form'>";
print "<tr><td colspan='2'><b>Attachment</b><input type='file' name='file' value=''></td></tr>";
print "<tr><td>Remarks</td><td><textarea name='sm_ppc_remarks' style='height:90;width:280'></textarea></td></tr>";
print "</table>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

### do.php

```
class PPC extends CONTROLLER{
    function workload(){
    global $db, $auth;

        $sql['ppc_m_id'] = $_POST['ppc_m_id'];  
        $sql['ppc_remarks_sales'] = $_POST['sm_ppc_remarks'];
        $sql['ppc_sales_attachment'] = fs_upload($_FILES['file']); 

    $insert = insertformat($sql);
    $query = $db->query("insert into ppc set $insert");

    if($query)
    $db->query("update sales set sm_ppc_remarks='{$sql['ppc_remarks_sales']}', sm_sales_attachment='{$sql['ppc_dpdate']}' where sm_id='{$sql['ppc_m_id']}' limit 1");

    if($query){
    message_set('Workload has been recorded');
    goback();
    }
    }
    }
```

when i filled the remark text area it was save in my data base, but in terms of saving the attchment(input type='file') it doesn't save.. i dont know what is know or something is missing.. thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

Add "enctype" in your `<form>` tag

```
<form name='mainform' method='post' action='do.php?ppc/workload' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: i try to add that but skill not working for me, sir this this is the problem fs_upload($_FILES['file']) it is possible to  make it $_POST[fs_upload($_FILES['file'])]

Comment: In your PHP code, try  print_r($_FILES);   and can you able to see the file informations?

Answer (score 0):

Missing "enctype"

`<form name='mainform' method='post' action='do.php?ppc/workload' enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: sir i think the problem is this fs_upload($_FILES['file']).. it is posible to make it $_POST[fs_upload($_FILES['file'])];